# Area51 Discuss rep requirements need to be revised so active users can prune out irrelevant questions

Tags: feature-request, area-51

There are currently 32 users who have enough rep to vote-to-close a questions and 3 users who can delete a question on Area51 Discuss but there are a ton of questions that are either not relevant or not useful anymore.

The questions I'm referring to usually fall into 3 groups:

- updates to the proposal description (no longer necessary after the change is made)
- requests to merge (which linger after the merge is completed)
- vote to close proposal (which linger after the proposal is closed)

Most of these questions are only useful in the short term until changes to a proposal are made. Afterward they just linger around as unnecessary cruft that makes it harder for users to see questions that are more current/relevant (such as new requests to close duplicate proposals).

Considering that:

- votes to close a question are only locked in for a short period of time
- The number of users who can actually vote to close or delete a question is extremely small
- As Area51 releases more sites and its active community is shrinking

I think it's necessary to either lower the cap to close/delete questions, or provide a means to dispose of old/irrelevant questions on Area51 discuss.

The high likelihood that most/all of the questions on discuss will quickly become irrelevant means that sufficient facilities need to be added so the active user community can trim the cruft.

Comment: We should get rep for Discuss, like we get on MSO. My massive amounts of upvotes need to be converted to rep!

Answer (score 2):

I just started pruning out "irrelevant questions" when I delete abandoned proposals. When proposals are deleted, the related discussions (as long as they no longer hold relevance) go with it.

So that solves a big chunk of the problem.

**In the meantime, feel free to flag discussions that are no longer relevant.**

What I am discovering is that finding these "irrelevant questions" is largely mechanical: Deleted proposals, launched proposals, status-completed, etc. This pruning might better be handled through a script or other automation. Community moderation might not be necessary to solve *this* problem.

We might need some changes to the way reputation is earned in Area 51. But my gut feel is that Area 51 Discussions should *not* be part of that equation.

Comment: Users who are opening discussions are the type who want to help new communities grow, in general. I suspect that rewarding these people will only help.